# How to create a csv file from a txt file with column separator after "x" amount of characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a txt file that looks like this:

```
MT0111500000000 Anniston-Oxford-Jacksonville, AL Metropolitan Statistical Area
MT0112220000000 Auburn-Opelika, AL Metropolitan Statistical Area  
MT0113820000000 Birmingham-Hoover, AL Metropolitan Statistical Area
```

I need to create a csv file from this, which I have little experience in, but have been learning and doing it, although likely not efficiently.

My issue right now is that when I use pandas, it is creating columns after the ",".  What I need is the column separator to be after the code on the left, "MT0113820000000", and although the codes do change, they are all the same length.

Thanks in advance, I know this is a really noobie question.

Here's my code currently:

```py
import pandas as pd

dataframe1 = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/andre/Desktop/bea_api_test/python-bureau-economic-analysis-api-client/testttt/output.txt")  
dataframe1.to_csv('output_.csv', index = None)
```

And the output:

```
COLUMN 1                                COLUMN 2
MT0111500000000 Anniston-Oxford-Jacksonville     | AL Metropolitan Statistical Area
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you've written? Sample output?

Comment: Yep, done. If you need anything else let me know.

Comment: check out `pandas.read_fwf` ("fwf" = fixed-width file)

Comment: What do you want the df to be? Just 2 columns of the MT thing then everything elset?

Comment: 2 columns, first column is the MT code, second column is the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, using `read_fwf` as mentioned in a comment above:

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

testdata = '''\
MT0111500000000 Anniston-Oxford-Jacksonville, AL Metropolitan Statistical Area
MT0112220000000 Auburn-Opelika, AL Metropolitan Statistical Area
MT0113820000000 Birmingham-Hoover, AL Metropolitan Statistical Area
'''

buff = StringIO(testdata)

df = pd.read_fwf(buff, header=None, colspecs=[(0, 15), (16, 64 * 1024)])

print(df.to_csv(index=False, columns=[0, 1], header=['COLUMN1', 'COLUMN2']))
```

Comment: Is there anyway to run it and not have commas and quotes added?

Comment: @unisonnn, if you create a CSV (**comma**-separated values) file, commas will be used to separate the columns. (But, you can use the `sep` argument to `to_csv` to write a file with a different separator)

Comment: The quotes are there to prevent the comma within the data from being interpreted as a second column separator. If you don't want the commas or quotes, maybe you should re-think whether you want to call your output file "CSV" and let us know what format you actually want.

Comment: I got it to work.  I pprinted the output from the provided csv after creating a dict from it.  There are no nested quotes.  This worked.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a CSV and I don't see a convenient way of convincing `read_csv` to do the right thing. Luckily, there seems to be an easy rule here. The stuff before the first space, then the stuff after. `str.split` does that.

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

#in_file = Path("C:/Users/andre/Desktop/bea_api_test/python-bureau-economic-analysis-api-client/testttt/output.txt")
in_file = Path("test.txt")
out_file = in_file.with_name(in_file.stem + "_").with_suffix(".csv")

    # test data
    open(in_file, "w").write("""\
    MT0111500000000 Anniston-Oxford-Jacksonville, AL Metropolitan Statistical Area
    MT0112220000000 Auburn-Opelika, AL Metropolitan Statistical Area  
    MT0113820000000 Birmingham-Hoover, AL Metropolitan Statistical Area""")
    
    # convert to csv
    pd.DataFrame([line.strip().split(" ",1) for line in open(in_file)],
        columns=["COLUMN1", "COLUMN2"]).to_csv(out_file, index=None, headr=False)
    
    # visual verification
    print(open(out_file).read())
```

Output

```
MT0111500000000,"Anniston-Oxford-Jacksonville, AL Metropolitan Statistical Area"
MT0112220000000,"Auburn-Opelika, AL Metropolitan Statistical Area"
MT0113820000000,"Birmingham-Hoover, AL Metropolitan Statistical Area"
```

In this example I immediately wrote the csv so that the dataframe is automatically deleted from memory. You could also do this with the CSV module, writing line at a time. This will use less memory because it don't have to hold the entire file in memory. And since `csv` is part of the standard python library, there is no external dependency on `pandas`. Adding a bit of file name handling

```
import csv
from pathlib import Path

#in_file = Path("C:/Users/andre/Desktop/bea_api_test/python-bureau-economic-analysis-api-client/testttt/output.txt")
in_file = Path("test.txt")
out_file = in_file.with_name(in_file.stem + "_").with_suffix(".csv")

# test data
open(in_file, "w").write("""\
MT0111500000000 Anniston-Oxford-Jacksonville, AL Metropolitan Statistical Area
MT0112220000000 Auburn-Opelika, AL Metropolitan Statistical Area  
MT0113820000000 Birmingham-Hoover, AL Metropolitan Statistical Area""")

# convert to csv
with open(in_file) as infp, open(out_file, "w") as outfp:
    writer = csv.writer(outfp)
    writer.writerows(line.strip().split(" ",1) for line in infp)

# visual verification
print(open(out_file).read())
```

Comment: When I run this code, it still splits it like this: "MT0112220000000 Auburn-Opelika,"

Comment: When I ran the first I got `MT0112220000000,"Auburn-Opelika, AL Metropolitan Statistical Area"`. Note that the second column is quoted so that its interior comma isn't considered a CSV comma.

Comment: I get an error: NameError: name 'p' is not defined

Comment: Ideally quotes would be removed, maybe I'm doing this ass-backwards, but I am attempting to create a dictionary from this and thus do not want nested quotes.

Comment: Oh, if you want a dict, that's a different matter. The quotes have to be there because otherwise the comma in the place name would make a new comma. A CSV reader removes those quotes as part of input processing.

Comment: If you want a dict, then `index = dict(line.strip().split(" ",1) for line in infp)`. If you want to keep the dataframe from example 1 for more processing and want an index, then keep the dataframe, and do `dataframe.set_index("COULUMN1")`.

Comment: Hmmm... okay.  And for me it is still splitting like this: "MT0111500000000 Anniston-Oxford-Jacksonville,"

Comment: That's odd. I updated the examples to be complete programs that write a test.txt file and read it when done. Included a copy/paste of the output I saw. Run this exact code and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the data at the first occurrence of the whitespace:

```
data = pd.read_table("data.txt", squeeze = True, header = None).str.split(" ", 1)
df = pd.DataFrame(data.tolist(), columns = ["column1", "column2"])

df.to_csv("df.csv")
```